# What is needed to embed power BI in a web page?

Tags: c#, powerbi

I am new to power bi and I don't have much knowledge about power bi licensing and what you can and can't do and also what you are required to have to do certain things.
My question is what do you have to have for licensing and software requirements to embed Power BI on a web page.

What I have tried:

I have read several articles but I am confused on exactly what is required.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, unless the question is in regard to some specific technical details discussed as part of a legal document you'd be better off checking official details or [forums with a focus on "legalese"](https://law.stackexchange.com/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to surface your Power BI reports in your own portal (App owns data) it will have to be backed by a Power BI capacity, embedded A, EM, or P SKU, however for developing the portal you can use a standard Power BI Pro license, then when it is ready switch to the Embedded capacity.

If you embed in your own portal your users do not need Power BI licenses to consume the reports, but your portal must handle all the user accounts, sign ups, security etc. Any report designers for Power BI need to have a Pro license to deploy reports to the service, that then get consumed by your portal.

Best place to start is the MS Doc's site that outlines what you can do with each capacity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this post. I could not find a clear statement if Power BI Embedded with A SKU capacity allows us to publish reports to users without any Power BI license. What still confuses me is the quote _"With A SKUs, all users who consume content require Pro licenses."_ in the article [Purchase Power BI Premium for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-premium-testing#purchase-a-skus-for-testing-and-other-scenarios). Is this a different scenario than Power BI embedded with SKU A. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: @spikey For that quote "With A SKUs, all users who consume content require Pro licenses.". So for testing you can use A SKU's to see what premium features you can use. A4 SKU's are dedicated capacity not shared. So you can test out features that may help you. You can then build your own portal on top of it, where users don't need Pro licenses